# IoC in .NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

What type of IoC is used for `AddSingleton`, `AddScoped`, or  `AddTransient` in ASO.NET Core? is it Unity, Spring.Net or Ninject? Or something Built-in specially for .NET Core?

Comment: The container used is [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection).

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you add to the project.

The project templates that include a DI container typically include Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection and instantiate the container that provided.

However you can bring your own. Sometimes you build in the same way and use that to initialise that third party containr. For instance with AutoFaq it can import the `ServicesContainer` instance from MS's library to initialise its content.

Comment: and Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection doesn't use Unity, am i right ?

Comment: It is its own DI container. Check out the source on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection).

Answer (score 0):

.NET core uses a built in IoC container. It is not unity by default. But you can bring in third party containers with much more advanced features than the built in container. Some examples include - Scrutor, AutoFac, Unity etc.
The built-in IoC container supports three kinds of lifetimes:

1. **Singleton:** IoC container will create and share a single instance of
   a service throughout the application's lifetime.
2. **Transient:** The IoC container will create a new instance of the
   specified service type every time you ask for it.
3. **Scoped:** IoC container will create an instance of the specified
   service type once per request and will be shared in a single
   request.